# Showing function is smooth

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-functions

$f:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^1$ such that $f(z, w)=z^mw^n$ for some integer $m$ and $n$. Then why $f$ is smooth? By definition a smooth function is differentiable infinitely. So in order to prove $f$ is smooth we need to show it is differentiable infinitely. But from how we defined $f$ it is of course differentiable infinitely thus $f$ is a smooth function. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Why is it "of course" differentiable infinitely? (I mean it's obvious to me and probably you as well but I'm guessing the purpose of this simple exercise is for you to explain why carefully using definition of smoothness on manifolds)

Comment: @peek-a-boo It means it has all partial derivatives of higher order. I think I am overlooking the definition. Could you guide me how to show it is differentiable infinitely?

Comment: You're certainly missing out on the definition. What you said is the definition of smoothness if the function is defined on an open subset of $\Bbb{C}^2$. However, $S^1\times S^1$ is NOT an open subset of $\Bbb{C}^2$. So the first question you need to ask yourself is what is the definition of smoothness when your domain is not an open subset, but rather a submanifold.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see. So I need to use different definition. We need to find another chart $g$ such that $f\circ g^{-1} $ is smooth. How can we find such $g$ ?

Comment: smoothness is a local property, and certainly $S^1\times S^1$ and $S^1$ are locally Euclidean. Now just pick some chart and see how the function seem locally.

Comment: First, notice that your $f$ comes from a map $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Restrictions of smooth maps to submanifolds are always smooth. The delicate part is to prove that indeed $f$ is smooth as a map with codomain $\mathbb{S}^1$. You need a result that states that if $S\subset N$ is an immersed submanifold, and the map $f: M\rightarrow N$ is smooth with $f(M)\subset S$, then $f: M\rightarrow S$ is smooth iff $f: M\rightarrow S$ is continuous. Check out Spivak's Volume 1 of Differential Geometry for this fact.